# How to view dependencies of AAR File

Tags: java, android, aar

I have an **AAR file created from Android studio**, my objective is to view dependencies of it.

Changed aar to zip and unzipped it.  It created `classes.jar`

When I opened Classes.jar using using [Tattletale](http://tattletale.jboss.org/) it gives an `error :   Invalid or corrupt jarfile classes.jar`

How to view dependencies of aar file?

Answer (score 0):

I referenced Jar in android studio project and was able to see all the classes in it.