# With gradle how to get the dependency tree of a library?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Say I want to retrieve with graddle the dependancy tree of this artifact : `com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.4.0`

How can I do ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Gradle to find dependency tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645071/using-gradle-to-find-dependency-tree)

Comment: @Nick no not really, me I don't even have any project, I just want to dependancy tree of com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.4.0 and i don't know how to do.

Comment: I already wrote to you that you can use the website https://stackoverflow.com/a/74235627/6066470

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that, An aar does not contain any dependency information by itself.

All the information of this aar is stored in pom.xml which can be found [here](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-firestore/24.4.0/firebase-firestore-24.4.0.pom) over google maven repo.

And this will only show you what `Gradle dependencies` command will do, and those are the [transitive dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management_terminology.html#sub:terminology_transitive_dependency) meaning the direct dependencies for this aar, Which By default, Gradle resolves them automatically.

the `pom.xml` for `com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.4.0`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
  <artifactId>firebase-firestore</artifactId>
  <version>24.4.0</version>
  <packaging>aar</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>androidx.annotation</groupId>
      <artifactId>annotation</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
      <artifactId>play-services-base</artifactId>
      <version>18.0.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <type>aar</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <name>firebase-firestore</name>
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
      <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>
</project>
```

This `pom.xml` include `com.google.android.gms` which has its own `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
  <artifactId>play-services-basement</artifactId>
  <version>18.1.0</version>
  <packaging>aar</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>androidx.collection</groupId>
      <artifactId>collection</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>androidx.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>core</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <type>aar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>androidx.fragment</groupId>
      <artifactId>fragment</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <type>aar</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <name>play-services-basement</name>
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>Android Software Development Kit License</name>
      <url>https://developer.android.com/studio/terms.html</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>
</project>
```

What I am trying to say, Is that unless you iterate the process and fetch the POM files of the dependencies yourself, with a custom task, All you can use is `gradle dependencies` command to check the transitive dependencies used by your project or module.

UPDATE:

You can easily start a new gradle project by following these simple steps.

1. `mkdir gradleExp`
2. `cd gradleExp`
3. `gradle init`  # 1.basic 1.groovy random name
4. update the empty `build.gradle` with the following

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.4.0"
}
```

5. `gradle dependencies` # to list all
6. `gradle dependencies --configuration compileClasspath`  # reduce output to show only Compile classpath for source set 'main'

NOTE: missing either `google()` or `mavenCentral()` will show some failure in the result shown.

Comment: Is it possible to createan empty project with just my dependency to run on it gradle dependencies? if yes how to do ?

Comment: yes, And i believe its pretty simple, I will update my answer now.

Comment: I have a strange problem with your solution, I open a new SO with this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74482724/gradle-dependencies-failed-for-an-unknown-reason

Comment: I have added an answer to your question, It should work fine now.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a dependency of your project you should be able to run

```
gradle dependencies
```

and see the dependency tree for your whole project (including the subtree for this artifact)

There are more details in the answer(s) to this question:
[Using Gradle to find dependency tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645071/using-gradle-to-find-dependency-tree)