# gradle dependencies FAILED for an unknown reason (maybe variant selection in metadata?)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I create a blank project :

1. `mkdir gradleExp`
2. `cd gradleExp`
3. `gradle init`  # 1.basic 1.groovy random name
4. update the empty `build.gradle` with the following

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0"
}
```

Then I run

```
dependencies --configuration compileClasspath
```

it's return me a failure:

[image]

But if i replace in `build.gradle` `androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0` by `androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0` then it's work perfectly :

[image]

What's wrong with `androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0`? how to know the exact reason of the failure ? My gradle version is 7.5.1 and I downloaded it from https://gradle.org/

Note: If it's can help, with the `--debug` parameter I can see :

> [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.component.model.ComponentAttributeMatcher] Selected matches [] from candidates [androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0 variant releaseVariantReleaseApiPublication, androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0 variant releaseVariantReleaseRuntimePublication, androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0 variant sourcesElements] for {org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.jvm.environment=standard-jvm, org.gradle.jvm.version=8, org.gradle.libraryelements=classes, org.gradle.usage=java-api}

I don't know if the problem is here but look like gradle cannot select a variant (ie : `Selected matches []` in the log)

this is the content of the `gradle-module-metadata` if it's can help:

```
{
  "formatVersion": "1.1",
  "component": {
    "group": "androidx.browser",
    "module": "browser",
    "version": "1.4.0",
    "attributes": {
      "org.gradle.status": "release"
    }
  },
  "createdBy": {
    "gradle": {
      "version": "7.2"
    }
  },
  "variants": [
    {
      "name": "releaseVariantReleaseApiPublication",
      "attributes": {
        "org.gradle.category": "library",
        "org.gradle.dependency.bundling": "external",
        "org.gradle.libraryelements": "aar",
        "org.gradle.usage": "java-api"
      },
      "dependencies": [
        {
          "group": "androidx.core",
          "module": "core",
          "version": {
            "requires": "1.1.0"
          }
        },
        {
          "group": "androidx.annotation",
          "module": "annotation",
          "version": {
            "requires": "1.1.0"
          }
        },
        {
          "group": "com.google.guava",
          "module": "listenablefuture",
          "version": {
            "requires": "1.0"
          }
        }
      ],
      "files": [
        {
          "name": "browser-1.4.0.aar",
          "url": "browser-1.4.0.aar",
          "size": 203214,
          "sha512": "5fabb554ca4dbea2c367df0decf175fee0a90bbdd7cc641c645b80a26e8bd13e85d5031c51bfbab25582a07f66e3eee829fadfe8b2e4e3383c4d877ce37935b2",
          "sha256": "e1906f84512f1ea5e4c926dbb915789ad8f7494fa4ee9ad245163f76185cecda",
          "sha1": "403c3cf31622ec0c70b3c0633be3e903c8062104",
          "md5": "8b6dfac591dd4b320351218bae97040e"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "releaseVariantReleaseRuntimePublication",
      "attributes": {
        "org.gradle.category": "library",
        "org.gradle.dependency.bundling": "external",
        "org.gradle.libraryelements": "aar",
        "org.gradle.usage": "java-runtime"
      },
      "dependencies": [
        {
          "group": "androidx.collection",
          "module": "collection",
          "version": {
            "requires": "1.1.0"
          }
        },
        {
          "group": "androidx.concurrent",
          "module": "concurrent-futures",
          "version": {
            "requires": "1.0.0"
          }
        },
        {
          "group": "androidx.interpolator",
          "module": "interpolator",
          "version": {
            "requires": "1.0.0"
          }
        },
        {
          "group": "androidx.core",
          "module": "core",
          "version": {
            "requires": "1.1.0"
          }
        },
        {
          "group": "androidx.annotation",
          "module": "annotation",
          "version": {
            "requires": "1.1.0"
          }
        },
        {
          "group": "com.google.guava",
          "module": "listenablefuture",
          "version": {
            "requires": "1.0"
          }
        }
      ],
      "files": [
        {
          "name": "browser-1.4.0.aar",
          "url": "browser-1.4.0.aar",
          "size": 203214,
          "sha512": "5fabb554ca4dbea2c367df0decf175fee0a90bbdd7cc641c645b80a26e8bd13e85d5031c51bfbab25582a07f66e3eee829fadfe8b2e4e3383c4d877ce37935b2",
          "sha256": "e1906f84512f1ea5e4c926dbb915789ad8f7494fa4ee9ad245163f76185cecda",
          "sha1": "403c3cf31622ec0c70b3c0633be3e903c8062104",
          "md5": "8b6dfac591dd4b320351218bae97040e"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "sourcesElements",
      "attributes": {
        "org.gradle.category": "documentation",
        "org.gradle.dependency.bundling": "external",
        "org.gradle.docstype": "sources",
        "org.gradle.usage": "java-runtime"
      },
      "files": [
        {
          "name": "browser-1.4.0-sources.jar",
          "url": "browser-1.4.0-sources.jar",
          "size": 96524,
          "sha512": "cd150044fd65d22c61f9d724a18b6a7386e4aed98644b146ffef0447b4f6f93044cb9fe58590f6111d33723733abc34039896a88a974ab0e465d05534294b101",
          "sha256": "3acbcce900ca5c2d03eb70d93136fc732d3b64dec185eaa86de3e64dff8ee792",
          "sha1": "2a2741f63427dcdb3b6821dd17703bc16ced13a1",
          "md5": "9eed77c8c21aeed4da0477c8bc6b72b9"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even `androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0` will work fine and as expected.

Here is the issue, in `androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0` or `1.0.0` as you mentioned, The output is exactly as expected. why?

For version [1.2.0](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=androidx.browser#androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0) and [1.0.0](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=androidx.browser#androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0), there are only two types of artifacts `pom` and `arr` which cause no issue in resolving.

for version [1.4.0](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=androidx.browser#androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0), There are 4 types which are     `source`,  `aar`,  `gradle-module-metadata`,  `pom`

By looking to those 4 when dealing with gradle, You can only assume that the top priority would be for `gradle-module-metadata` which is actually right according to the official docs [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sec:supported-metadata-formats).

There is clearly an issue with resolving `gradle-module-metadata` , so let me try to re-configure the order

According to [gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sec:supported-metadata-formats), You can easily do that with the following

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://repo.mycompany.com/repo"
        metadataSources {
            mavenPom()
            artifact()
        }
    }
}
```

So the code of the repositories section should look like this

```
repositories {
    
    mavenCentral()
    { metadataSources {
        mavenPom()
        }
    }
    google()
    { metadataSources {
        mavenPom()
        }
    }
}
```

This will cause them to ignore the `gradle-module-metadata` and prioritize the `pom.xml`

For some reason, This will not behave as expected, And It did not work unless I have added `configurations.implementation.canBeResolved = true`

so, The entire `build.gradle` would look like

```
plugins {

    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    
    mavenCentral()
    { metadataSources {
        mavenPom()
        }
    }
    google()
    { metadataSources {
        mavenPom()
        }
    }
}

configurations.implementation.canBeResolved = true


dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0'
}
```

And will result with only showing the dependencies of the implementation section using either `gradle dependencies` command or `gradle dependencies --configuration implementation` for limited output.